# Solr results with * are empty, without * I have results

Tags: indexing, solr, prefix

I have this text field with the value of "object-a1"
When I search for: object-a I get the object.
When I search for: object-a* I get an empty result.

My field is indexed like this:

```
     <fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
        <analyzer type="index">
            <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" 
                    splitOnNumerics="0" 
                    splitOnCaseChange="0"
                    preserveOriginal="1"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
        <analyzer type="query">
            <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" 
                    splitOnNumerics="0" 
                    splitOnCaseChange="0"
                    preserveOriginal="1"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use wildcards (*), you are hitting a little-known issue with Solr called [multiterm](https://lucidworks.com/blog/2011/11/29/whats-with-lowercasing-wildcard-multiterm-queries-in-solr/). Specifically, WordDelimiterFilterFactory is not MultiTerm-aware (no *(multi)* flag marking it so on [the Solr Start listing for the component](http://www.solr-start.com/info/analyzers/#WordDelimiterFilterFactory))

Wildcards are not very efficient, you may want to consider using [EdgeNGram filter](http://www.solr-start.com/info/analyzers/#EdgeNGramFilterFactory) instead at the end of the chain.

Comment: Thanks! It's good to know this but I didn't find a multi-term factory that will work like the wordDelimiter.

Comment: There is not one. That's why I said try using EdgeNGram after your wordDelimiter *instead* of using wildcards.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Property as shown per below LINK.

```
catenateAll="1" causes all subword parts to be catenated:
```

https://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters